# How to call Java script method when navigation pane item clicked

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created one 'sub area' item 'Site Map' of CRM 2011. My requirement is to call .aspx page on click of that item. But I should use javascript to call on click of that item because, I have to pass some query string values along with that URL. I'm using Url="http:////WebResources/SitemapCall.js" attribute in  tag.  But, how can we call particular 'method' from that JScript file..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SubArea is not supporting javascript, we can call html webresource from SubArea tag.

SubArea Id="nav_subArea" Title = "New Sub Area" Url="$webresource:MyPage.htm"/>

And call javascript function on load of html page to call desired URL along with query string.

```
function onLoadRedirectToURL()
 {
var userId = parent.Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
var baseURL = 'http://www.ServcerName/newPage.aspx';
window.navigate(baseURL + '?userId=' + userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SubArea is not designed to support javascript. You are able to put your Javascript function into URL of subarea, but you will have difficulties with your page opening. Better way is use Button on Ribbon Bar and it supports Javascript.

```
<CommandDefinitions>
  <CommandDefinition Id="CustomButton">
  <EnableRules/>
  <DisplayRules/>
  <Actions>
    <JavaScriptFunction Library=“$webresource:new_CustomAction“ FunctionName=“CustomActionFunction“></JavaScriptFunction>
  </Actions>
  </CommandDefinition>
</CommandDefinitions>
```

Comment: How to give a reference for this <CommandDefinition> in <SubArea> tag..?

Comment: SubArea is not designed to support javascript. You are able to put your Javascript function into URL of subarea, but you will have difficulties with your page opening. Better way is use Button on Ribbon Bar and it supports Javascript.